# Check if specific word occur in a file, if not print there's no word in a file

Tags: python-3.8

The code below opens the file and checks if specific word occur in file by reading lines, if so prints the line in which the word is. I don't know how to change the last line of code to print ' There is no {find} in your file' only when specific word doesn't occur in a file at all.

```
word = input('Input the word to find: ')
this_line = 0
find = word
with open (n, 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.readlines()
    last = read_data[-1]

for line in read_data:
    this_line += 1
    if find in line:
        print (f' {find} is in line {this_line}')
        if read_data is last:
            break
            
    print(f' No {find} in file.')
```

Comment: Maybe elif would help? https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0):

The typical answer would be

```
if find in line: 
    ...
else
    print ("no {} in line".format(find))
```

However, Python has a unique feature- an else block for for loops.
It executes only if there were no 'break' keywords encountered in the process of looping.
[See this here link](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) for further detail. Example they used matches your problem pretty closely.

```
for item in container:
    if search_something(item):
        # Found it!
        process(item)
        break
else:
    # Didn't find anything..
    not_found_in_container()
```

By the looks of it, either one of these would work. But I would favor the second because its more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
word = input('Input the word to find: ')
this_line = 0
words = 0
find = word
with open (n, 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.readlines()
    last = read_data[-1]

for line in read_data:
    this_line += 1

    if find in line:
        words +=1
        print (f' {find} is in line {this_line}')
        if read_data is last:

            break

if words == 0:
    print(f' No {find} in {n}.')
else:
    print('--------------------------------')
    print(f'{find} appears {words} times in {n}')
```